# RecyclerView taking too long to load

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I'm creating a recycler view for 500 items. It is calling onCreateViewHolder and onBindViewHolder for every item and taking too long to load. The UI skipped around 522 frames because of this. How can I make it load faster?

```
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
      if(holder.getItemViewType() == SHUFFLE_ROW) {
           Log.d(TAG, "Position " + position);
           if(searchClicked) {
                    final SearchBoxHolder searchHolder = (SearchBoxHolder) holder;
                    searchHolder.backIcon.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                         }
                }
                else {
                    ShuffleAllViewHolder shuffleHolder = (ShuffleAllViewHolder) holder;
                    shuffleHolder.numOfSongs.setText(mSongList.size() + " Songs");
                }


            }
else if(holder.getItemViewType() == SONG_ROW) {
                ListViewHolder listViewHolder = (ListViewHolder) holder;
                Song currentSong = mSongList.get(position-1);
                listViewHolder.albumTitle.setText(currentSong.getTitle());
                listViewHolder.albumArtist.setText(currentSong.getArtist());
                Picasso.with(mContext).load(currentSong.getAlbumArt()).placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder)
                        .resize(70, 70)
                        .centerCrop()
                        .into(listViewHolder.albumImage);
            }
}

public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
if(viewType == SHUFFLE_ROW) {
                if(searchClicked) {
                    view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.search_row, parent, false);

                    return new SearchBoxHolder(view);
                }
                else {
                    view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.shuffle_all_row, parent, false);

                    return new ShuffleAllViewHolder(view);
                }
            }
            else {
                view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.song_row, parent,
                        false);
                return new ListViewHolder(view);
            }


    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        if(position == 0) {
            return SHUFFLE_ROW;
        }
        else return SONG_ROW;
    }
```

I don't understand why it is taking so long to load.

Comment: there are many things you can do to optimise your code. Start with setting a unique id for each item and setHasStableIds(true). Override getItemId(int position) and return a unique id for each unique item.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I was using `RecyclerView` inside `ScrollView` which was causing it to load like a snail. Just removed the scrollview and everything works like a charm.

Comment: its worked. loading time reduced for 12 seconds 4 seconds ,For meRecyclerView is inside NestedScrollView

Comment: Any ulternate to do with recyclerview with nested scrollview bez i ahve same thing what @RameshBhupathi have

Answer (score 1):

Imho you have a couple of options:

- paginate the list - load e.g. first 50 items, when user reaches the bottom, load 50 more ... (like suggested [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/2p99lw/recyclerview_scrollbar_with_lots_of_items_very/))
- start with an empty list and a progress bar. Then populate the array (e.g. progressively) from a background thread and call `notifyDataSetChanged()` after each update.

Second option could be viable if the dataset is fixed/known (like in your case having a list of songs).

Comment: Yeah second option is good. But I think recycler view with just 500 items should not be slow. So I'm trying to figure out if there is a problem. I'll do the 2nd option if all else fails